# How to update the content of Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, record

I have one table **TABLE_EXAM**. i need to update the value of specific record by passing
id. But my code is not able to update the code. i don't understand what is wrong in my code.
Please give me some hint or reference... 
Thanks in advance..
Here is my code for reference....

```
public void updateExamDetails(int id,ObjectiveWiseQuestion owq)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery=("update exam set (examdetails, subchawise, examtype, noquestion, marks, subject_id, chapter_id) where exam_id ='"+ id +"'");
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_NO_QUESTION, owq.getNoOfQuestion());
            values.put(COLUMN_MARKS, owq.getMarks());
            values.put(COLUMN_CHAP_ID, owq.getChapterId());
            values.put(COLUMN_SUB_ID, owq.getSubjectId());
            values.put(COLUMN_SUBCHAWISE,owq.getSubChapwise());
            values.put(COLUMN_EXAM_TYPE, owq.getExamType());
            values.put(COLUMN_EXAM_DETAILS, owq.getExamDetails());
            db.insert(TABLE_EXAM, null, values);
            db.close();

        } 
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Logcat have one warning..

```
WARN/System.err(7227): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error: , while compiling: update exam set ( examdetails=?, subchawise=?, examtype=?, noquestion=?, marks=?, subject_id=?, chapter_id=? ) where exam_id ='1'
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I'd expect your query string to require some parameters to bind (typically something like `set examdetails=?, subchawise=?, ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard way of doing it:

```
String query = "UPDATE exam SET examdetails = ?, subchawise = ?, examtype = ?, noquestion = ?, marks = ?, subject_id = ?, chapter_id = ? WHERE exam_id = ?";

String[] params = new String[]{owq.getExamDetails(), owq.getSubChapwise(), owq.getExamType(), owq.getNoOfQuestion(), owq.getMarks(), String.valueOf(owq.getSubjectId()), String.valueOf(owq.getChapterId()), id};

db.rawQuery(query, params);
```

Comment: ohh sorry, i just fixed this `String[] params`. See my updated answer. If still doesnt work, then write me the error too

Comment: it show error on owq.getChapterId, owq.getSubjectId which are integer

Comment: encapsulate your any integer value into `String.valueOf(your_int_value)` to parse it into string. See my updated answer

Comment: this 3 lines are sufficient? or i need to create cursor object?

Comment: these 3 lines are sufficient to update a record. but if you need to get returned data then you may use cursor. but in this case i dont think its require. did it work?

Comment: no error...but i need to compile it...whether value are correctly passed or not

Answer (score -2):

You can execute query directly as

```
b.execute("update exam set examdetails="yourvalue" and subchawise="your value" and examtype="your value" where exam_id ="id name");
```

I have tried this feature for updating the sqlite table row. I think, this is work fine to you.. best of luck...

Comment: b.execute("update exam  examdetails=""yourvalue" and subchawise="your value" and examtype="your value" where where exam_id ="id name");

Comment: Hello please follow this query

Comment: b.execute("update exam set examdetails="yourvalue" and subchawise="your value" and examtype="your value" where exam_id ="id name");